# Does the type of SATA port matter in regards to fileservers?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, bandwidth, file-server

I want to build a dedicated home file server that will also be used for streaming numerous video files. Does the SATA bandwidth matter if I will be using 1tb 7200rpm drives? Also, would I be able to downgrade the drive in any way without noticeable performance hits (disk speed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the SATA bandwidth matter if I will be using 1 TB 7200 RPM drives?

The SATA bandwidth does not matter.

Even relative old SATA-II (3.0 gigabit/sec) is able to push 270 MB/sec.
That is a lot faster than your disk can supply.

The only exceptions to this are:

1. If you use an SSD.
2. If you use [port multipliers](http://www.sata-io.org/technology/port_multipliers.asp) to add multiple drives to a single SATA channel.

> Also, would I be able to downgrade the drive in any way without noticeable performance hits

**Streaming video files** does not require a high RPM disk since the data is usually read sequentially. There is no advantage in using 7200 RPM drives for this. A 5400 RPM drive will work just fine, and might use less power and generate less heat.